# how to escape "\"in ssh-copy-id?

Tags: ssh, escape-characters, openssh

I'm connected to Ubuntu server that is a member of a corporate Active Directory domain via likewise-open. The users are in the form `mydomain\myuser`. I can connect to it via ssh, escaping the `\` with another `\`:

```
ssh mydomain\\myuser@myserver
```

I've generated a pair of keys via `ssh-keygen`, then tried to copy it to the remote machine. The user I'm using in the local machine is not the same I want to copy the key into, so I issued the command:

```
ssh-copy-id mydomain\\myuser@myserver
```

and the output:

```
password:
password:
password:
mydomainyuser@myserver's password:
Received disconnect from myserver: 2: Too many authentication failures for myuserydomain
```

prompting me for the local user's password three times, and then the `\\` actually worked as a single `\` escaping the first `m` in `mydomain`. Am I getting this straight? And how can I escape that `\` and correctly copy key to the remote machine?

EDIT: also `ssh-copy-id myuser@mydomain.com@myserver` turned out to be a valid syntax.. However, the question was about escaping the `\`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you are escaping it for the shell, but `ssh-copy-id` is also attempting to interpret it. This should work:

```
ssh-copy-id 'mydomain\\myuser@myserver'
```